# Multiple exe files in one solution, all referencing a single public class

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I have a c# console project (vs2012) that is getting big. Currently I am calling multiple 'methods' one after the other. As I add more methods I would like to be able to break them out into multiple executable files, to be ran as scheduled apps, but still be able to reference (and change using tortoise SVN) a public class of rules of which they all will reference. Do I have to create a dll to accomplish this or is there a simpler way? Sorry, I'm new to all of this. I have found similar questions but I either did not understand them or they weren't quite what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you need to build a DLL and reference it from whatever project needs the code stored there.
It is just a matter to add a new Library project to your solution, create a public class and insert the methods that should be called from the other projects

Click the Menu File and choose Add Project
[image]

Then go to your Solution Explorer Window, click the Console Application and right click on references
[image]

and select from the Solution folder the Project of your class library
[image]

Now go to the predefined Class1 and add the following code

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    // Class that contains methods and data to be used/shared by various applications
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        { }

        public void Show(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

and in your ConsoleApplication1 add the following code

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        // A sample console application that uses the library project....
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 c=new Class1();
            c.Show("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a overkill explanation for such a question but +1 for the endeavors.

Comment: It was funny to do and I hope useful for the future passers by

Comment: Thanks for the step by step pictures. It helps seeing as I have never created a dll before.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to create a dll to accomplish this or is there a simpler
>   way?

If you want to achieve *shared logic* and modularity then the answer is no, no simpler way and you should create assembly (DLL) using the Class Library Project template in VS, write your `public` classes, build it and reference it from your EXE's projects.

I would recommend you to have a solution with the Executables and the Class Library project together so you'll be able to enjoy maintainability and good synchronization with your Class Library by referencing it *by Project* and not *by Assembly*.